# Database in cleardb MySQL of Cloud Foundry is not generated with Eclipse IDE

Tags: mysql, eclipse, cloud-foundry

I generated Cloud Foundry MySQL Service in Eclipse IDE. MySQL service works well. And I make connection of this MySQL service with Eclipse database development perspective successfully. Please see my image.

[image]

But problem is I can't create any tables in this Cloud Foundry MySQL database.
I make simple SQL script of Eclipse database perspective like below:

[image]

The error message is **No database selected**. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You have to select a database in which your tables will be created

Comment: thanks for your reply. So, i typed "use ad067305b..." line. But the same error messages is thrown. I think this is the matter of privilege. But i have no idea.

Comment: Instead of writing `use ad06***;`, could you try to replace all `family` strings by `ad_06***.family` ?